# Is u(n) a periodic signal?

Tags: signal

[image: photo taken from Dr. J. S. Chitode]
It’s given in the book Dr. J. S. Chitode that u(n) repeats after every sample but as we have searched on google quora answers are saying that u(t) is not periodic. So, now I’m confused

In my perception u(n) isn’t periodic since it don’t repeat between any deterministic period!

Comment: Don't you think this question is missing a pretty important detail? Like, the definition of your function?

Comment: It’s an unit step signal

Comment: Probably he means the *unit step* function which sometimes is denoted by \$u(t)\$ (and of course is not periodic).

Comment: @Arshdeep Singh: Please show us the text that says it repeats after every sample. Maybe there is a misunderstanding.

Comment: I have edited this question by adding image of the text given in the book

Comment: What is \$n\$ in this context? A constant or the independent variable (time or sample index)?

Comment: u(n) is a Discrete signal. Hence ‘n’ is discrete time domain representation it exists only on integral values

Comment: So, yes, we have a conflict between this sentence and the common understanding of what \$u\$ is. If you can't produce the definition of \$u(n)\$ **from that same book**, this question is likely to be closed as unclear, since we can't read the mind of the author as little as you can telepathically.

Comment: Just now my teacher have told me not to get confused on this one just analyse the periodicity from where the signal have some value other than zero. That’s the point from where your signals actually starts

Comment: u(n)=1 is a discrete signal with period equal to the sampling increment. In the same way that a repetitive impulse is periodic in the continuous domain.

Comment: This comment stream almost qualifies as a book. VTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Generally, a discrete signal x(n) is said to be periodic with periodicity N, if x(n) = x(n+N) for all values of n. Here u(n) *seems* to be periodic with N = 1 for all values of n. Yet u(n) is not completely periodic. As you can see, **for n = -1**, the periodicity lost, as u(-1) is not equal to u(0). It would have been periodic, if all samples were 1, extended till **-infinity**. We can generate such a periodic signal like this --> u(n) + u(-n-1). If you plot this signal, you can see that its periodic at all values of n with periodicity N = 1.

[image]

Comment: Is it okay for a periodic signal to give different value when greater than zero and different value when less than zero. Should I accept that its period is its sampling increment but value of u(n) for less than zero it is ‘0’ and for greater than zero it is ‘1’. Periodic signal should follow the formula u(n + N) = u(n) in discrete time domain & here if n=-1 & N=1 then ; 0=1 by the above formula.

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh That was a good catch bro. Thank you for pointing out that. Had to rectify my mistake. I hope the edited answer clears your doubt.